# Finding First Img Within HTML Accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target the first image in each accordion group. I've included an example of one of them.

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix">All Videos</a>
</div>
     <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse">


          <div id="video-scroll6" class="accordion-inner">
             <div style="width: 3080px;">

               <img src="demo.jpg" data-video="1" />
               <img src="demo.jpg" data-video="2" />

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

This is what I've tried with no luck so far...

```
$(".accordion-heading").click(function () {

    $(this).find(".accordion-inner div img").first().attr('data-video');

});
```

Comment: From your supplied markup, `.accordion-heading` contains no `img`'s...

Comment: @ahren, that's what I did `find(".accordion-inner div img")` maybe that's not the right way of doing it. But that's how I was trying to target the div with the images.

Comment: Do you know why it does not work? jQuery's find looks inside the element you select. There is only one child inside the div accordion-heading and that is the single link. What you are looking for is in the next sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it this way..which makes it easier down the road if you want to choose an image other than the first

```
$(".accordion-heading").click(function() {

 // :eq(0) = 1st img, :eq(1) = 2nd img and so on...
$(this).next().find(".accordion-inner div img").eq(0).data('video') ;

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/Ybe7g/3/)

Comment: Please don't use the `:eq()` selector, it cannot make use of `querySelectorAll()` which has performance implications; instead, use `.eq()`

Comment: There's always buzzkiller ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).next()​.find('img').first().data('video');
```

[This is the working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WESBH/)

In jQuery 1.8 we simply access the .data('attr') rather than `attr('data-name')`

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting an error in the console that doesn't even let my page load. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . `

Comment: @Jako are you using jQuery 1.8?

Comment: @Ohgodway, yes jQuery v1.8.2

Comment: @Jako that's odd, works fine in the jsFiddle. can't see any reason why this won't work.

Comment: yes that is weird. I'm not entirely sure. Thanks for your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).next().find( $(this).next().find(".accordion-inner div img").first().attr('data-video')).first().attr('data-video');
```

Since you're clicking on the div before the div that contains your images, you need to use the `.next()` selector.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ybe7g/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".accordion-inner div img").first().attr('video')
```

should work.